# The C# project referencing unmanaged third-party assembly builds fine in Debug, but fails in Release configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I have a project in C#, which references unmanaged third-party DLL (which is [ChilkatDotNet2.dll](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-dotnet.asp), but it seems not to matter). The third-party DLL is delivered in 2 versions, x86 and x64. The project references the x86 version - `processorArchitecture=x86` in the appropriate `<Reference>` element. It builds just fine in both Debug|Any CPU and Release|Any CPU.

Now I change the reference to x64 version of third-party DLL - `processorArchitecture=AMD64`. (Don't ask me why, please :)). The Debug|Any CPU builds just fine again. But the Release|Any CPU fails with the error: `An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: ChilkatDotNet2.dll`.

What could be the reason? I would think it's because VS itself runs as 32-bit process (right?), but why does it build fine in Debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem seems to have hidden in the fact the project was upgraded from older versions of VS (I suppose, starting from 2005). I have re-created it from scratch, added all necessary stuff, and it works! Moreover, it became IDENTICAL to the bad one, and this makes me insane: one works, another doesn't.

So, I gave up since "the sun is rising? don't touch anything there". :) Thanks to everyone who suggested options to try - I appreciate your efforts (+1).

Accepting my own answer to mark the thread as complete, but don't vote it up - it doesn't contain useful info...

Comment: If you still have the old one around, try deleting the .sou (hidden) file to see if that does the trick

Answer (score 2):

Likely the platform type in your release configuration is incorrect.  If you are strongly referencing x86/AMD64 assemblies then your build cannot be ANY CPU and must be platform-specific

Comment: yes, it's quite logical and makes sense, but why does Debug builds then? I tried making those configurations identical - only names were different. But it still failed for Release... I can live with the behavior I described, but it's a bit uncomfortable to leave the magic behind...

Comment: Debug and Release builds have their own configuration, so one was probably ANY CPU and the other AMD64

Comment: I'd love it to be that simple, but unfortunately it isn't - both Debug and Release are Any CPU... Thanks for your time, anyway

Comment: Have you checked all of the projects?  Other possibility I suppose is a dependency somewhere down the line...

Comment: Yes. I have even removed all but 1 project, to narrow down the problem - still no luck...

Comment: I have also tried on a brand new solution. I added a single project to it, and in that project I added a reference to third-party DLL. And it builds fine in any case - when it references x86 or x64, when the reference contains `processorArchitecture=AMD64` or `processorArchitecture=x86`... So, it's definitely something in the project definition, but what exactly? It drives me nuts...

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised this is a compile time error.  In my experience these problems manifest as `BadImageFormatException` at run time.  Although your solution platform is Any CPU I would check the target platform of the referencing project to be sure it is set to Any CPU as well.  Also, by default visual studio will create application projects using the x86 configuration, not Any CPU.  So even if the referencing project is set to Any CPU the entry application project is ultimately the deciding factor of how referenced Any CPU targeted projects are JIT'd.